# Notation for graph weights over vertices *and* edges?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, soft-question

Consider a graph $G=(V,E)$ in which both vertices and edges have a weight. I define it as a function $\omega$ from $V \cup E$ to the weight set.

This seems fine to me, but some colleagues are disturbed by the fact that $\omega$ takes elements from $V$ and $E$. They see them as two different sets, which is correct, but $V \cup E$ also is a set, and it seems to me that $\omega$ may take elements in it.

May you please tell me if my definition is ok? Is it awkward? Is there a better one?

I would like to avoid having two different weight functions, like for instance $\omega$ and $\omega'$ or $\omega_V$ and $\omega_E$. I find them awful in the expressions I deal with, like:
$$\omega(v) \longleftarrow \sum_{u\in N(v)} \frac{\omega(u,v)}{\sum_{w\in N(u)} \omega(u,w)}\cdot\omega(u)$$

Comment: "avoid having two different weight functions" saves a little for you at the cost of an awkard interpretative requirement for your prospective readers.

Comment: That's the actual question: is my notation awkward? It seems that some of us think so, which surprises me. I'll edit the question to make it explicit.

Comment: It could make sense to "mix" $V$ and $E$, if it wasn't actually $V$ but more like "hyperedges of size one". If the way you use your weighting functions afterwards is coherent with this interpretation, maybe you can make it more natural than two different weight functions.

Comment: @Matthieu Latapy: To understand what you're trying to do, it would help if you would edit your question to show the actual definition of your proposed weight function, as well as a theorem to illustrate its usefulness.

Comment: @quasi: Thanks for your suggestions. The definition is simply a function from $V\cup E$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which I then use in many contexts. I added a typical instance of expressions I deal with (although it is among the simplest).

Comment: @Matthieu Latapy: Now that you've provided more context, I withdraw the objection I made in my initial comment. But rather than define the weight function on $V\cup E$, instead use Misha Lavrov's suggested compromise: Define two functions $\omega_V$ and $\omega_E$, and then simply declare that $\omega$ will denote either of them (the number of arguments will make clear which one is intended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two objections to be made.

First, people think of vertices and edges as different *types* of things, and want the inputs to a function to always be the same type. This is not a distinction set theory makes, but it's a distinction many people's intuition makes, especially when coming from a CS background.

Second, there are some rare, implausible cases where the definition could have unexpected results. Say your graph has three vertices: $a$, $b$, and $\{a,b\}$. If all three possible edges are present, and you think of an edge as a set of two vertices, then the edges are $\{a,b\}$, $\{a, \{a,b\}\}$, and $\{b, \{a,b\}\}$. You'll notice that the last vertex is the same set as the first edge; so your function $\omega : V \cup E \to \mathbb R$ would have to assign the same weight to that vertex and that edge. Again, it is rare for this issue to come up, and most people would not even consider this behavior - but it is inelegant for the definition to depend on what sort of objects the vertices are, or on how exactly the edges are defined.

Anyway, both of these issues are solved if you define two functions, say $\omega : V \to \mathbb R$ and $\omega' : E \to \mathbb R$. Since you do not like this, one compromise is to say:

> The graph has two weight functions: a vertex weight function $V \to \mathbb R$ and an edge weight function $E \to \mathbb R$. In a slight abuse of notation, we will use $\omega$ to denote both functions.

This allows you to keep using the notation you wanted for the rest of your write-up.

Comment: This is interesting, thank you. There is indeed an ambiguity when $E\cap V \neq \emptyset$, and I clearly need to avoid it. Then, the _compromise_ you propose seems sound to me.

Comment: I would relate the first part of your answer to polymorphism, though. It is nowadays common to have programming language functions that take different types as inputs, and this is actually very old: arithmetic operators typically take integers and floats as inputs and then handle them differently. This leads some language to have different operators for integers and floats (like + and +. for instance), while others use the same operator. It seems there is no definitive answer.